# How to code something like setAutoresizingMask in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, bitwise-operators, autoresizingmask

I am pretty naive when it comes to Bitwise operations so am wondering how you go about coding something like the setAutoresizingMask method of the UIView class.

I'd like to be able to create a method that allows me to pass in enumerations separated with the | (pipe?) character.